# how can I make a singular loop wait in python

Tags: python, loops

I want to make a loop pause for 5 seconds but I have multiple loops so if I use time.sleep the other loop stop working

```
while a==True:
    b=b+1.5
    print("Something: "+str(b))
    time.sleep(5)
    clear() #I defined a clear function to clear the screen


while a==True:
    print("Something!")  #here is the nonoperating part and I tested it doesn't gets cleared by clear function
```

Comment: Does `clear()` also clear `a`? Because once you break out of that first `while` loop, I don't know how you're expecting to get into the second from the given code.

Comment: nope it doesn't clear the variables it only clears the output on the screen

Comment: I am just glancing at this but a is no longer equal to True - otherwise it would still be in the first loop - I suspect it is in the first loop and will remain there.

Comment: So what are you expecting to happen? The first loop to sleep and the second to immediately run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want both loops to run concurrently. So run each loop in its own thread:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def clear():
    pass # some implementation

a = True
b = 0.0

def fun():
    global b
    while a==True:
        b=b+1.5
        print("Something: "+str(b))
        time.sleep(5)
        clear() #I defined a clear function to clear the screen

t = Thread(target=fun, daemon=True) # thread will end when main thread terminates
t.start()
while a==True:
    time.sleep(1) # for demo purposes
    print("Something!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using time.sleep is, that this is a blocking function, It can't be run in the background synchronously with another chunk of code. There are two approaches to overcoming this problem:

- split your python program into multiple synchronous threads or processes.
- run your python code asynchronous.

In my opinion, your problem looks like a good example to solve with asyncio:

```
import asyncio

async def function1():
    while a:        # You can leave out '==True', as 'while a' alone will do the job 
        b += 1.5
        print("Something {}".format(b))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        clear()
        
async def function2():
    while a:
        print("Something!")
        await asyncio.sleep() # give the loop function some time to sleep, be it just so tiny. Otherwise yout program will never be able to swith between loops


if __name__=="__main__":
    asyncio.run(\
        asyncio.gather(\
            function1(),
            function2(),
            return_exceptions=True
            )
        )
```

by utilizing asyncio you can chieve cooperative multitasking or in other words, having one function in one thread in one process overseeing many coroutines at the same time in the background but executing always only one at a time.

This fits your problem well, as you are mostly waiting for some time to pass between execution of different bits of code and not really demanding "true" simultaneous multiprocessing. By not using Threads or Processes, you will make your programm less resource intensive.